# JavaScript Showing blank values even after using proper syntax

Tags: javascript

Following is my HTML form

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return check()">
    <input placeholder="Enter Username" type="text" id="user">
    <input placeholder="Enter Your Password" type="password" id="pass">
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript I am using in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
        {
            var ll = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML;
            alert(ll);
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

The problem with the code is that whenever I am putting a value in the user field and then click on the login button the JS code executed but it shows always the blank value in the `var ll` i have created. Why so as even my syntax are perfect. The code was working perfect yesterday but today whn i am using the same code it's showing blank values. Why So?

Comment: Use `value` to get the value of textbox. `innerHTML` is for getting the inner-HTML of an element.

Comment: @Tushar that should be an answer.

Comment: Which has been asked million times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function check()
        {
            var ll = document.getElementById("user").value;
            alert(ll);
            return false;
        }
```

```html
<form accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return check()">
    <input placeholder="Enter Username" type="text" id="user">
    <input placeholder="Enter Your Password" type="password" id="pass"/>
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use value property instead of InnerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   document.getElementById("user").value;
```

innerHTML is used just for writing

Answer (score 1):

You should use document.getElementById("user").value; to get the values entered inside input field.

document.getElementById("user").innerHTML will get the text content of an element say for example,
SAMPLE TEXT

document.getElementById("sampletxt").innerHTML will display "SAMPLE TEXT".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` tags are self-closing and thus don't have an `innerHTML` property, you get the value of the input field by the appropriately named `value` property.

This makes sense when you think about it, but just wait until you start working with `<textarea>` tags...